# Refactor/Replace Double type variable to Decimal / NSDecimalNumber in iOS swfit

Tags: ios, swift

Actually I have an App in which heavy I did some heavy mathematical calculations, but due to `double` variable type (which is base 2), I've faced the precision errors.

Now I have been learning how to deal with this situation there are two alternatives `Decimal` or `NSDecimalNumber`. I chose to go with `Decimal` here, but doing changes over 500 files are quite cumbersome task.
Any Idea how to get this done.

I've been handling the price/currency and mathematics operations.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: A global search and replace for `Double` might find many cases, but you’re likely have to clean this up one by one yourself.

Comment: But can you clarify “heavy mathematical calculations”? If it’s seriously computationally intensive with binary types, it’s going to be worse with decimal types. And many binary-type mathematical functions are not available for `Decimal`. Or when you say “heavy”, are you merely saying “frequent”. In short, given the amount of changes necessary to make this work, make sure you’re 100% sure confident that this is the way to go.

Comment: @Rob as heavy I mean "frequent", I've been using addition, subtraction, multiply and divide a lot.
but with double 0.74 have become 0.733333333333 then I got some errors here. Hope after converting to Double, I may not have this kind of problem

Comment: @Rob I'm currently confuse about how to deal with this situation, that's why I haven't started yet, instead I asked from the community

Comment: If 0.74 became 0.73333333333333, then that’s something very different and `Decimal` won’t solve that. What it can address is when 0.74 became 0.7399999999999. And even then, often formatting number output with `NumberFormatter` is easier. Don’t get me wrong, `Decimal` is perfect when dealing with currencies and the like, but just be absolutely sure before changing 500 (!) files.

Comment: But if you’ve done your due diligence, and are 100% sure you want to do that conversion, there is no built in refactoring tool that will do these changes for you. But you can do shift+command+F do replacing there.

Comment: The fact that you have 500 files worries me, though, because I wonder if buried in one of those files might be something that really requires binary floating point behaviors. I’d hate to see you do 499 files and on the last one realize, “whoops, I guess this won’t work...”.

Comment: If you are going to use Decimal make sure to always use its string initializer